# Motorola EMDK | Profile Editor is empty | Android Studio (Windows)

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, motorola-emdk

I want to create a new Profile using the EMDK Profile Wizard but no profiles are available.

[image]

I'm currently using Android Studio on Windows

Comment: Can you please add which Android Studio and EMDK versions are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is to run the EMDK's Integrator that you can find under `Symbol EMDK for Android v4.0` in your Start menu:

[image]

This will ask if you want to install the EMDK on Android Studio or Eclipse ADT and apply the needed changes.
You may expect some strange behaviour like this when you upgrade your Android Studio environment.

Just keep your EMDK updated to the latest version as we're working to keep it in sync Android tools. Latest version available is v4.0, you can find it on [Zebra's support website](https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN/Resolution?solutionId=100998&redirectForm=search&searchQuery=%3FsearchType%3Dsimple%26searchTerm%3Demdk%20for%20android%204.0).